# for loop to check if number is prime or not Javascript / JS

Tags: javascript

I wanted to create a function to check if the number is prime or not. I found a solution for this challenge and I passed it. But I can't quite understand why num 2 returns as true.

If anyone could share your knowledge, it would be great!

```
function checkNum(i) {
for(let j = 2 ; j < i; j++) {
if(i % j === 0) {
return false;
}
```

the below is the whole solution.
So.... When i is 2 in this code, why does it return true? Is it because i is not greater than j? so for loop doesn't evaluate it....? and returns true?

```js
function sumPrimes(num) {

  let sum = 0;

  function checkNum(i) {
    for (let j = 2; j < i; j++) {
      if (i % j === 0) {
        return false;
      }
    }
    return true;
  }

  for (let i = 2; i <= num; i++) {
    if (checkNum(i)) {
      sum += i;
    }
  }

  return sum;
}

console.log(sumPrimes(10));
```

Comment: **Is it because i is not greater than j?** Yes, that's the reason.

Comment: `i = 2` and `j = 2`. When the check `j < i` comes up, it returns `false` because `2` is not less than `2`. Therefore, the loop ends before it starts.

Comment: Following what @VLAZ said, since the loop is immediately escape, the return true that is in that function gets ran. There is an error with this, because (-inf, 1] {interval notation} all return true, even though they shouldn't because they aren't primes. This is fine for this example because the last `for` loop starts at 2

Comment: Cool. It's all clear now. Thanks everyone!!